# About the general solution of this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suposse I have one differential equation of the form:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dy_{1}(x)}{dx}-ay_{1}(x)=\frac{dy_{2}(x)}{dx}
\end{eqnarray}
Is there a direct way to express $y_{2}(x)=f(x,y_{1}(x))$ in the general solution of $y_{1}(x)$? Or to relate the both in general terms? The general solution will be of the form:
\begin{eqnarray}
y_{1}(x)=e^{-ax}\left(C + \int dx e^{ax}\left(\frac{dy_{2}(x)}{dx}\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}
by using integrating factors. But this does not give a general formula for $y_{1}(x,y_{2}(x))$. If we integrate by parts, the $y_{2}(x)$ is still contained in the rhs inside an integral sign. So, should I assume there is no simple functional relation between $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ in this case? By simple relation meaning that one can just factor our $y_{2}(x)$ or $y_{1}(x)$ on a single equation.

Comment: This *is* the general formula that relates $y_1$ and $y_2$, it can't be "simplified". Integration by parts has the benefit of removing the differentiation of $y_2$, it that matters.

Comment: The problem is that $y_1(x)$ depends not on the value of $y_2(x)$ in certain point, but on values in infinite number of points.